# Junit test when case ignored

Tags: java, junit, spring-test

I have a simple controller with a method:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/{" + WebConstants.ATTACHMENT_ID + "}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public void getAttachmentById(@PathVariable(value = WebConstants.ATTACHMENT_ID) Integer attachmentId,
                                  HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    logger.info("Start Document Attachment Controller: Fetch attachment by id." );

    // fetch the document attachment
    DocumentAttachment attachment = documentAttachmentService.getDocumentAttachmentById(attachmentId);
    final File file = new File(attachment.getPath() + Constants.FILE_SEPERATOR + attachment.getFileName());


    // convert the file to byte array and write it to the output stream
    byte[] contentAsBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(file));

    String encoding = Constants.UTF8_FORMAT;
    response.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
    /** set header */
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"");

    /** write the file */
    response.getOutputStream().write(contentAsBytes);
    /** return to view */
    response.flushBuffer();
}
```

And I am trying to convert it with a Junit test. My code for the unit test is posted bellow:

```
@InjectMocks
DocumentAttachmentController documentAttachmentController;

@Mock
HttpServletResponse response;

@Autowired
DocumentAttachmentService documentAttachmentService;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    log.debug("initMocks()");
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void testGetAttachmentById() throws IOException {
    log.debug("Test getAttachmentById");

    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.setDocumentId(1);

    DocumentAttachment attachment = new DocumentAttachment();
    attachment.setFileName("fileName");
    attachment.setId(1);
    attachment.setOriginalFileName("originFileName");
    attachment.setPath("/");
    attachment.setDocument(doc);

    when(documentAttachmentService.getDocumentAttachmentById(anyInt())).thenReturn(attachment);

    documentAttachmentController.getAttachmentById(1, response);
```

The problem is that it throws java.lang.NullPointerException.
I debugged my code and it seems that the condition 
documentAttachmentService.getDocumentAttachmentById(attachmentId)
from the application not take in advantage at all the when statement and return null. I cannot understand what it is wrong.
Any ideas?
Thanx

Comment: **1)** The question is tagged `junit3` but you're using  `spring4/5` annotations, which one is it? **2)** Are you running with a [`SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/testing.html) and also how did you specify you spring test context (see previous link) so that your beans get injected?